# How to update field type in a document using Java MongoDB Reactive driver?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-java, reactive-streams

I have a document in MongoDB collection:

```
  {
    "fOne": "strValue",
    "fTwo": {
      "nestedFArray": [
        {
          "dateF": "2010-01-02T13:00:01"
        },
        {
          "dateF": "2010-01-02T13:00:01"
        }
      ],
      "nestedFObject": {
        "anotherDateF": "2010-01-02T13:00:01"
      }
    }
  }
```

fields `fTwo.nestedFArray[0].dateF`, `fTwo.nestedFArray[1].dateF`, `fTwo.nestedFObject.anotherDateF` stored as a string type; How to replace types of this field with **DateTime** type when I have a json paths for fields using [java mongo reactive driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/)?

**`$.fTwo.nestedFArray[0].dateF`**

**`$.fTwo.nestedFArray[1].dateF`**

**`$.fTwo.nestedFObject.anotherDateF`**

Answer (score 1):

The query is an aggregation which converts the string date values to `Date` values. The result list from the aggregation is iterated and the modified documents are updated in a for-loop. Note the code assumes a collection with multiple input documents.

*The Java Code:*

```
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOneModel;
import com.mongodb.client.model.WriteModel;
import com.mongodb.bulk.BulkWriteResult;
import java.util.*;

public class MongoReact {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws Throwable {

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("test");

        List<Bson> pipeline =    
            Arrays.asList(
                new Document("$project", 
                    new Document("fTwo.nestedFObject.anotherDateF", 
                        new Document("$dateFromString", 
                            new Document("dateString", "$fTwo.nestedFObject.anotherDateF")
                        )
                    )
                    .append("fTwo.nestedFArray",
                        new Document("$map", 
                            new Document("input", "$fTwo.nestedFArray") 
                                .append("as", "e")
                                .append("in",
                                    new Document("dateF",
                                        new Document("$dateFromString", 
                                            new Document("dateString", "$$e.dateF")
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                )
            );

        SubscriberHelpers.ObservableSubscriber<Document> querySubscriber =
            new SubscriberHelpers.ObservableSubscriber<Document>();
        collection.aggregate(pipeline).subscribe(querySubscriber);
        querySubscriber.await();
        List<Document> resultDocs = querySubscriber.getReceived();

        List<WriteModel<Document>> updates = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Document doc : resultDocs) {
            ObjectId id = (ObjectId) doc.get("_id");
            Document f2Doc = (Document) doc.get("fTwo");
            updates.add(new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
                                new Document("_id", id), 
                                new Document("$set", new Document("fTwo", f2Doc))
            ));
        }

        SubscriberHelpers.PrintSubscriber<BulkWriteResult> updateSubscriber = 
            new SubscriberHelpers.PrintSubscriber<BulkWriteResult>("Bulk write results: %s");
        collection.bulkWrite(updates).subscribe(updateSubscriber);
        updateSubscriber.await();

        mongoClient.close();
    }
}
```

*NOTES:*

The `SubscriberHelpers` is a utility class used in the above code. I have used it as shown in the *Quick Tour* (with examples) section of the [Reactive Streams Java Driver page](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/1.10/getting-started/quick-tour/).

The source code for the `SubscriberHelpers.java` can be found at: [mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/examples/tour/src/main/tour/](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/tree/master/examples/tour/src/main/tour). The usage of the code and examples source code is also there - you can compile and use it.

I have used MongoDB server 4.0, Java SE 8, [MongoDB Reactive Streams driver 1.10.0](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/) and mongodb-driver-async  3.9.0 to work with the above code.